# Webhook laravel Error spatie (The signature is invalid)

Tags: php, laravel

The signature is invalid.

`{"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\WebhookClient\\Exceptions\\WebhookFailed(code: 0): The signature is invalid. at /home//public_html//vendor/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/src/Exceptions/WebhookFailed.php:11)`

Answer (score 0):

in my case
the error is in

> 'signature_header_name' => 'Signature',

must be the sent from webhook server

> 'signature_header_name' => 'tookan_shared_secret',

can also make custom validation
ex

> ```
> use Illuminate\Http\Request; use Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator; use
> ```
>
> Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookConfig; use
> Spatie\WebhookClient\Exceptions\WebhookFailed;
>
> class CustomSignatureValidator implements SignatureValidator {
> public function isValid(Request $request, WebhookConfig $config): bool

Comment: Is `tookan_shared_secret` correct above? I have this same issue and was trying to figure out your solution but can't. Would you mind elaborating the details of your solution?

Comment: tookan_shared_secret as i remember it's secret credentials given from tookan